# Seven swans a-swimming

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the famous Christmas carol ["The Twelve Days of Christmas"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twelve_Days_of_Christmas_(song)), presents like "geese a-laying" and "swans a-swimming" are mentioned. What does the "a" refer to in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What does the "a" refer to in this context?**

The **a-** is a prefix  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/a-) used in **a-laying** and **a-swimming**

> 2. literary or archaic (used before a present participle) in the act or process of: come a-running; go a-hunting etc...